# What's permission 's'?

Tags: permissions, file-permissions, ls

I did a ls on my /bin in OS X. I got the following output. What's the 's' permission in rcp line?

```
/Users/snihalani/.oh-my-zsh on master at 11:12AM
➜ lsa /bin 
--------------.oh-my-zsh--------------
total 6632
drwxr-xr-x@ 39 root  wheel   1.3K Aug 22 11:12 ./
drwxr-xr-x@ 34 root  wheel   1.2K Aug 22 11:12 ../
-rwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel    18K Jun 20 16:24 [*
-r-xr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   1.3M Aug 21 23:34 bash*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    19K Aug 22 11:11 cat*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    29K Aug 21 23:34 chmod*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    24K Aug 22 03:15 cp*
-rwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel   386K Aug 15 05:36 csh*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    24K Aug 22 11:10 date*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    27K Aug 22 11:12 dd*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    19K Aug 22 03:15 df*
-r-xr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    14K Jun 20 16:53 domainname*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    14K Aug 11 03:31 echo*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    53K Aug 15 05:27 ed*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    19K Aug 11 03:30 expr*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    14K Aug 22 03:15 hostname*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    14K Jul 26 12:13 kill*
-r-xr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   1.3M Aug 15 16:58 ksh*
-r-xr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    72K Aug 22 10:30 launchctl*
-rwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel    15K Aug 15 19:54 link*
-rwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel    15K Aug 15 19:54 ln*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    34K Aug 22 11:12 ls*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    14K Aug 21 23:34 mkdir*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    20K Aug 20 10:20 mv*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   109K Jul 27 02:16 pax*
-rwsr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    46K Aug 22 00:56 ps*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    14K Aug 11 03:06 pwd*
-r-sr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    29K Jul 25 15:21 rcp*
-rwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel    19K Aug 22 11:12 rm*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    14K Aug 17 17:49 rmdir*
-r-xr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   1.3M Aug 22 11:11 sh*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    14K Aug 12 07:12 sleep*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    32K Jul 26 17:28 stty*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    34K Jun 20 16:51 sync*
-rwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel   386K Aug 15 05:36 tcsh*
-rwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel    18K Jun 20 16:24 test*
-rwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel    19K Aug 22 11:12 unlink*
-r-xr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    14K Jun 20 17:57 wait4path*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   622K Aug 22 11:10 zsh*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) bit.  It makes the program run as the user who owns it regardless of who runs it.